# Adding JMenuBar to Flamingo JRibbonFrame?

Tags: java, macos, ribbon

I'm trying to port my app to Mac OS but as my program is based on Flamingo library it doesn't have any menu bar. As you may know Mac OS menu bar is fundamental part for any software, So Is there a way to add a menu bar to Mac OS and still using Flamingo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by overriding the  setJMenuBar() method in JRibbonFrame class and let it use the JFrame(Super) implementation.